# convert php sql query while loop to for loop

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, while-loop

In my code, `'product'` table is returning every product details in the table.

Now I want to get specific product details of 0 to 5th product. How can I change this while loop to a for loop?

Code:

```
public function getProducts(){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM shop_product";
    $resultSet = Array();
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    while($fetchResult = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $resultSet[] = $fetchResult;
    }
    mysql_free_result($result);

    return $resultSet;
}
```

Comment: Your existing query returns every column for every row in your table. If you just want five rows this is incredibly wasteful. Change your query to add a limit: `SELECT * FROM shop_product LIMIT 0,5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply change your query instead to return top **five** rows.

```
SELECT * FROM shop_product LIMIT 0,5
```

(**or**)

If you don't prefer the above solution,  you could use [`array_slice()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to get a portion of the array..

```
while($fetchResult = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $resultSet[] = $fetchResult;
    }
    $fiverowsarray = array_slice($resultSet, 0 , 5); //<--- You can add like this..
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with LIMIT and Where  conditions

```
public function getProducts(){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM shop_product LIMIT 0,5";
    $resultSet = Array();
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    while($fetchResult = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $resultSet[] = $fetchResult;
    }
    mysql_free_result($result);

    return $resultSet;
}
```

Comment: `$product_id` isn't set anywhere so this will fail straight way. In any case, why limit to five when the `where` clause will only return one product anyway? This doesn't help the OP at all.

Comment: @Mike W User says  I want to get specific product details of 0 to 5th product

Comment: Yes he does. Your query, if it worked, would return just one product, not five.

Comment: Sorry product_id is not required here